# Want a message box to be displayed when any application closes

Tags: android

i am new to android programming
My concern is:
Whenever a particular application is closed, i want a message box to be displayed which asks the user to save certain files related to the application(for example kml file in google earth). Do i need to develope an app for it or can it be done changing my phone/system settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data of applications should be saved in the background when "closing"/pausing an app instead of NOT closing the app and showing dialog boxes (that's really unintuitive).
Also have a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) to see why Android apps don't "close" but are rather paused and their lifecycle managed by the Android system.

Comment: I think u got me wrong. Let me give u an example: suppose i am using google earth in my android phone. Now when i close google earth, i want a message to be displayed asking me i want to save the .kml cache file in a location which is fixed by me(or in an sqlite data base). If i select "yes" then it saves that .kml file and preferrably asks me the name with which i would save the file.

Comment: What you are talking about is a behaviour which should be implemented in the apps you are using and not something system-wide (IMHO). So please read the link given in the answer.